# How to attach three differet layout to adapter

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to attached three different layout in adapter using holder and getItemViewType but m not able to get expecting result.Please look into my below code and suggest me.

I want to apply layout based on msg.mode, So how to use viewType + msg.mode. Currently m using only msg.mode to attached layout

getView() function is below -

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Message msg = getItem(position);
       int viewType = this.getItemViewType(position);

        switch(msg.mode)
        {
            case 0:
                    UserHolderDay holder1;
                    View v = convertView;

                    if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService     (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.template_message_day, parent, false);

                        holder1 = new UserHolderDay();
                        holder1.txtTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
                        v.setTag(holder1);
                    }
                    else {
                        holder1 = (UserHolderDay)v.getTag();
                    }

                    Typeface  tf_dark = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
                    holder1.txtTime.setTypeface(tf_dark);

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String strDate = "";
                    try {
                        cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(msg.date));
                        int year1 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int month1 = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int date1 = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) ;

                        String strMon = Get_Month(month1+1);
                        strDate = String.valueOf(date1)+" "+strMon+" "+String.valueOf(year1);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        strDate = msg.date;
                    }

                    if (holder1.txtTime != null)
                    holder1.txtTime.setText(strDate);

                // return the created view
                return v;

            case 1:
                UserHolderMode1 holder2;

                    View v1 = convertView;
                    if (v1 == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v1 = vi.inflate(R.layout.template_message_right, parent, false);

                        holder2 = new UserHolderMode1 ();
                        holder2.txtMsg = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                        holder2.txtTime = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
                        holder2.tv_status = (TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
                        v1.setTag(holder2);
                    }
                    else {
                        holder2 = (UserHolderMode1)v1.getTag();
                    }

                    Typeface tf_dark1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

                    holder2.txtMsg.setTypeface(tf_dark1);
                    holder2.txtTime.setTypeface(tf_dark1);
                    holder2.tv_status.setTypeface(tf_dark1);


                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                    DateFormat dfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

                    try {
                        String time = dfTime.format(dateFormat1.parse(msg.date));
                        holder2.txtTime.setText("At "+time);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        holder2.txtTime.setText("At "+msg.date);
                    }


                     holder2.txtMsg.setText(msg.msg);


                    if(msg.status == -1)
                    {
                        holder2.tv_status.setText("Pending");
                    }
                    else  if(msg.status == 0)
                    {
                        holder2.tv_status.setText("Sent");
                    }
                    else  if(msg.status == 1)
                    {
                        holder2.tv_status.setText("Received");
                    }
                    else  if(msg.status == 2)
                    {
                        holder2.tv_status.setText("Read");
                    }
                     holder2.txtMsg.setMinEms(10);

                // return the created view
                return v1;

            case 2:

                UserHolderMode2 holder3;

                View v2 = convertView;
                if (v2 == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v2 = vi.inflate(R.layout.template_message_right, parent, false);

                    holder3 = new UserHolderMode2 ();
                    holder3.txtMsg = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                    holder3.txtTime = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
                    v2.setTag(holder3);
                }
                else {
                    holder3 = (UserHolderMode2)v2.getTag();
                }

                Typeface  tf_dark2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

                holder3.txtMsg.setTypeface(tf_dark2);
                holder3.txtTime.setTypeface(tf_dark2);

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                DateFormat dfTime2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

                try {
                    String time = dfTime2.format(dateFormat2.parse(msg.date));
                    holder3.txtTime.setText("At "+time);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    holder3.txtTime.setText("At "+msg.date);
                }


                holder3.txtMsg.setText(msg.msg);

                // return the created view
                return v2;

        }
}
```

Comment: What problem getting using current code?

Comment: Plz check my ques. I have edited it n it will be grt if you help me

Comment: sarika : currently which layout is showing in ListView rows?

Comment: based on msg.mode = 1 it showing template_message_right

Comment: @prosper k : join chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111194/chatschpp

Comment: Are you overriding getViewTypeCount()??

Comment: yeah, code is -
 @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

Comment: you can set visibility Visible or Gone for that it may help you.

Comment: @amitshrma: i dnt think so that will help. three layouts are totaly diffrent